# Switching language Controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new at laravel , and using this controller to switch my language

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\Http\Requests; 
use Config; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LanguageController extends Controller {
     public function switchLang($lang)
     {
         if (array_key_exists($lang, Config::get('languages'))) {
             Session::set('applocale', $lang);
         }
         return Redirect::back();
     } 
}
```

and here's my route :

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', ['as'=>'lang.switch', 'uses'=>'LanguageController@switchLang']);
```

and at the app.blade , I have used this :

```
{{ Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()] }}
<a><span id="country-lang"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a> 

<ul id="lang-style" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled">
    @foreach (Config::get('languages') as $lang => $language)
        @if ($lang != App::getLocale())
            <li>
                <a class="text-center" href="{{ route('lang.switch', $lang) }}">
                    <img alt="England" src="{{asset('website/images/icons/flags/')}}{{$language}}.jpg" />
                </a>            
            </li>

         @endif
     @endforeach                             
</ul>
```

It has been worked prefectly at local server and switching the languages, but at online serve it's not , you can check  the website onlie here

premiumcaregold.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the language variable to the session only, not to the App facade. You should also it to the App like this:

```
App::setLocale($locale);
```

This will only set the locale for the current request. The next request will load the default locale of your application. To persist the selected language throughout the user session, you need to make a locale middleware and wrap all the routes that require translation.

In the middleware, you get the language from the session and set it to the current request.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $locale = 'en';

    if ( Session::has('applocale') {
        $locale = Session::get('applocale');
    }

    App::setlocale($locale);
}
```

Comment: Yes , I have made a middleware but still not working with me

Comment: Are you using `App::setlocale('en');`? What's the error ?

Comment: The problem is that : Session::get('locale');  back null every time and i don't know why ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's `Session::get('applocale');` Use 'applocale' instead of 'locale'. I fixed my code sample.

Comment: Then please, mark my answer. Always mark answers that help you, that's how stackoverflow works. Thanks :)

Comment: I did , Thank you